# Change table row background color

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to try to change the row's background color for a given time interval:

```
var $tr = $tableBody.find('tr[id=' + id + ']');

setTimeout(function () {
    $tr.css("background-color", "red");
    $tr.effect("highlight", {}, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

Unfortunately the above is not working.

Do I need the `css` whilst adding the row? Or is there a better way by defining a style?

**EDIT**
Here is an example [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5tsafx0p/)

Comment: `$tr.css("background-color", "red");` is not wrong. Are you getting errors? Is your selector correct? ...

Comment: What do you mean by `above not working`? Do you have jQuery UI loaded?

Comment: Hey did anyone of these answers helped you to fix that ?

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Unfortunately none of the answers are working. I'm adding jquery-ui script and the $tr selector is also correct because I'm changing other row details. However, the background is not changing.

Comment: Then can you please add more code here with html and css or give us an jsfiddle for that ? Also check the animate function that i have provided you in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tsafx0p/4/) that works on click.

The problem with you code was that you were using `','` after each `var` declaration

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').on('click',function(){
      var $tbl = $('#myTable');
      var $tblbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
      var $tr = $tblbody.find('tr[id=' + 1 + ']');

      $tr.addClass('highlight');
    });

})
```

Comment: My problem is with `$tableBody.find('tr[id=' + id + ']');`'  because if I use '`('#1').addClass('highlight');` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not altering the elements CSS directly, but instead adding a class to the element that is set in the CSS style sheets:

//CSS

```
.highlight{background-color:red}
```

//JS add the highlight class to the row

```
$('#' + id).addClass('highlight');
```

//set a timeout to remove the highlight class after a given time-frame (2 seconds in this example):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#' + id).removeClass('highlight')}, 2000)
```

This way you are not altering its CSS as such - and you can use the highlight class multiple times and for other things as well.

Note that you need to determine a trigger for the addClass aspect - otherwise this will add it on page load, and like all jQuery instances - you need the jquery library added to your page and the $(document).ready(function(){}) wrapper around all of it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you're looking for

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $tr.effect( "highlight", { color: "red" }, 2000 );
}, 1000);
```

also, be sure you're including jquery UI library as well :)

see this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h43aj0nt/)